# What does '((->) a)' mean?

Tags: haskell, types, type-constructor

I've seen this type before without knowing what it means. Does it mean something 
and/or does it have a name?

```
Prelude> :m Data.Functor
Prelude Data.Functor> :t flip . (flip (<$>))
flip . (flip (<$>))
:: Functor ((->) b) => (b -> a) -> b -> (a -> c) -> c
```

Comment: It's the ordinary function arrow written in prefix form. That is, `(->) a b` is the same as `a -> b`.

Comment: If you like `(3+)` instead of `((+) 3)`, you can think of `((->) a)` as `(a ->)` - even though that's not valid syntax, it gives you an idea of what it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add to Matt Fenwick and josefg's more technical answers, the `((->) a` can be read as the type constructor that forms values that depend on an `a`.  One example: suppose you have teams  whose membership varies over time.  One possible way to represent this is like this:

```
-- | The type of a's that depend on a point in time, using t as the timeline type.
type Historical t a = t -> a

observe :: Historical t a -> t -> a
observe = ($)

-- | The membership of a team is a list of persons whose composition can change
-- from day to day.
membership :: Team -> Historical Day [Person]
membership = ...
```

`((->) a)` is a `Functor`, `Applicative` and `Monad`, which means that the type class operations are available, and they have very useful interpretations when used with `Historical t`.

First example: `fmap` applies a function to a time-dependent value.  So for example,

```
-- The number of persons in a Team, depending on the Day:
membershipCount :: Team -> Historical Day Int
membershipCount = fmap length . membership
```

The Applicative `<*>` operation gives you *simultaneity*:

```
-- The joint membership of team1 and team2, depending on the Day:
(++) <$> membership team1 <*> membership team2 :: Historical Day [Person]
```

Though actually, since we have `instance Monoid [a]` and `instance Monoid m => Monoid t -> m`, the previous example can be written like this:

```
import Data.Monoid

membership team1 ++ membership team2
```

Monad gives you composition:

```
personToManager :: Person -> Historical Day Manager
personToManager = ...

managerToVP :: Manager -> Historical Day VP
managerToVP = ...

personToVP :: Person -> Historical Day VP
personToVP p = personToManager p >>= managerToVP
```

Note also that `((->) r` is exactly the same as the `Reader r` monad.  If you understand the code above you pretty much understand `Reader`.

---

**EDIT:** I should clarify that time-dependent values is just *one use* of the function/Reader monad.  There are other uses; the classic example use case of the Reader monad is to thread configuration values through a computation.  It's got rather more uses than just that, as the example above shows.

Answer (score 9):

Actually, `((->) a)` is not a type but a partially applied **type constructor**.

Just like functions, type constructors can be partially applied in Haskell.

You can check the **kind** of something in GHCi:

```
ghci> :k (->)
(->) :: * -> * -> *

ghci> :k (->) Int
(->) Int :: * -> *
```

All values have [types of kind](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Kind) `*`; type constructors have kinds like `* -> *`, `* -> * -> *`, etc.

Comment: Pedantry mode: all values have *types* of kind `*`.

Answer (score 5):

In Haskell, `(->) a` is from `a -> something`. Remember that you can turn an operator to a prefixed function by using parans. ie `(+) 1 1 == 2`. So in this case the "operator" is the type constructor `->`. It's used this way because a functor needs a type constructor with 1 variable, but `->` has 2. So we partially apply it.

It may help you to realize that `<$>` for `((->) a)` is just `(.)`

Comment: I see, so `((->) a)` has type `*->*`?

Comment: To be a bit more explicit, I would add that `(->)` has kind `* -> * -> *` while `(->) a` has kind `* -> *`.

Comment: @Carlos no, `((->) a` is not a type!  But if you s/type/kind/, it's correct.